# SELECT data from two tables with multiple arguments

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to select data from two tables. 
In first table i store some content in default language.
Second table store's translations for data contained in first table.

I want to retrieve row for specific language.

For example:
id, content, id_language, content_translation.

I,ve made query like this:

```
SELECT content_static.*,
content_static_t.*
FROM content_static
LEFT JOIN content_static_t on content_static_t.parent_id = content_static.id
WHERE content_static.id = 1;
```

It works fine, but when i have 2 languages it displays two rows, each one for each language.

I want to display only one row, only for one language.
I also wonder it is possible to get data for multiple ID's from table content_static only in SQL query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa076/2

I add to query addition condition ( AND content_static_t.language_id = '2'). When I set argument to '2' it's ok, but when I set it to '4' i get no data.
In this case i wat to display only data from the table content_static.

Comment: Which language do you want to show?  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Use distinct Clause

Comment: you probably looking for `group_concat()`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @BHouse DISTINCT isn't going to help much here.

Comment: @lazyLizzard can u give sample output screenshot pls. It will return same row because you might have a different value in any other column from * list

Comment: I've add link to sql fiddle  to the post and I modify the query. It works fine when the translation to specific language is available in table content_static_t. I want to retrive data from the second table also when the is no translation for specific language.

Comment: @LazyLizzard its got 2 different  id's in content_static_t, if you remove content_static_t.id from select as you are joining t.id = t1.parentid and place distinct clause, it will return one row as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

if you use the Primary Key in the WHERE statement then it is very simple, just use TOP 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 content_static.*, content_static_t.*
FROM content_static
LEFT JOIN content_static_t on content_static_t.parent_id = content_static.id
WHERE content_static.id = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have simply forgotton to add the condition for the language:

```
SELECT cs.*, cst.*
FROM content_static cs
LEFT JOIN content_static_t cst on cst.parent_id = cs.id AND cst.language_id = 4
WHERE cs.id = 1;
```

Change or remove the `WHERE` clause, if you want more IDs.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this please tell me why?